# C++ accessing value type of an unordered_map

Tags: c++, typedef, unordered-map

I am looking at the code of a file distributed by Adobe:

https://github.com/stlab/adobe_source_libraries/blob/00ec524725ebe41b77d6d5b5d796c056cdf08585/test/json/any_json_helper.cpp

The part of the code I am interested in is:

```
struct any_json_helper_t {
    typedef any                                 value_type;
    typedef string                              key_type;
    typedef string                              string_type;
    typedef unordered_map<key_type, value_type> object_type;
    typedef vector<value_type>                  array_type;
    typedef object_type::value_type             pair_type;
```

Error:

```
clang++ -o json json.cpp -std=c++14
json.cpp:105:13: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::__1::unordered_map<std::__1::basic_string<char>, any,
  std::__1::hash<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, std::__1::equal_to<std::__1::basic_string<char> >,
  std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const std::__1::basic_string<char>, any> > >'; did you mean simply 'value_type'?
typedef object_type::value_type pair_type;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        value_t
json.cpp:100:17: note: 'value_type' declared here
    typedef any value_type;
```

Am I doing something wrong? (it seems to implicitely use `any` instead of `value_type` and thus can't find `object_type::value_type`). How could I make this work (beside using `value_type` directly of course as suggested by compiler)?

## EDIT

`any` is not available in c++14 (as mentioned in an answer). I implemented my own version in this particular case.

```
struct any
{
public:
    any() : ptr(nullptr) {}
private:
    struct base_t
    {
        virtual ~base_t() {}
    };

    base_t* ptr { nullptr };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is only since C++17.
If you want to compile it with C++14 you can use `boost::any` calss from [*boost*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) lib

Comment: Sorry I implemented my own;-) I should have mentioned that ... and that could be where the problem is?

Comment: Yes, could be there! Show your custom `any` class implemantation please!

Comment: I stripped it down, and the problem is still there... (see edit)

Comment: @user18490 Forget, my last comment, it is working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fca906842d95eb8

Comment: @user18490 Be sure you are placing the `any` struct declaration before `any_json_helper_t`

Comment: Your example compile with clang++ ... I think my code is the same ... so I will need to look into why it doesn't compile then. I guess the order is not what I assume it is... Thx for your input.